# is_unique in codeigniter with condition check

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi friends its there is any way to filter is_unique in code-igniter with some condition based, for example I have a table pages with attribute id , page name , status and I'm using `is_unique[page.page_name]` I'm giving status as 0 and 1 if the status is 1 it **should not check for constraint** `is_unique` is there is any possibility

Comment: `if($status != 1) {
   $is_unique =  '|is_unique[page.page_name]'
} else {
   $is_unique =  ''
}`

Answer (score 0):

**Your Controller**

```
function hasSameName($name)
{
    $this->your_model->hasSameName($name);
}
```

**Your Model**

```
     function hasSameName($name){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('mytable');
        $this->db->where('page_name',$name);
        $data=$this->db->get();
        $result=$data->row();
       $status=$result->status;
     if(empty($status)){
       return true;
       }
   else if($status==0){
     return true;
    }
  else{
  return false;
  }
    }
```

**Your Validation**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('page_name', 'Page Name', 'callback_hasSameName');
```

[see more for callBack](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html/#callbacks)